# Hom sheaves between group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X/S$ be a proper smooth curve of genus 2 over a connected scheme $S$ (of all residue characteristics 0), and let $s,s' : S\rightarrow X$ be two sections. Let $p\in S$ be a geometric point. Then we have an exact sequence of fundamental groups:

$$1\rightarrow \pi_1(X_p,s(p))\rightarrow \pi_1(X,s(p))\rightarrow\pi_1(S,p)\rightarrow 1$$
and a similar sequence using $s'$. Each sequence is split by the section $s$ or $s'$, and hence we obtain an action of $\pi_1(S,p)$ on $\pi_1(X_p,s(p))$ via $s_*$, and an action of $\pi_1(S,p)$ on $\pi_1(X_p,s'(p))$ via $s'_*$. If $S$ is Noetherian, then by the Galois correspondence this data gives us two pro-finite etale group schemes, which we denote by:
$$\pi_1(X/S,s'),\qquad \pi_1(X/S,s)$$
which are not necessarily isomorphic. However, their geometric fibers are $\pi_1(X_p,s(p))$ and $\pi_1(X_p,s'(p))$ and are canonically isomorphic up to inner automorphisms (as groups they are both isomorphic to $\langle x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 | [x_1,y_1][x_2,y_2]\rangle$)

I'm trying to understand the statement of 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9501003.pdf, where it claims that somehow the sheaves
$$\mathcal{H}om_S^\text{surj}(\pi_1(X/S,s),G)/\pi_1(X/S,s)$$ and $$\mathcal{H}om_S^\text{surj}(\pi_1(X/S,s'),G)/\pi_1(X/S,s')$$ **are** isomorphic (and canonically so) (where the quotient acts via inner automorphisms).

I'd be exceedingly grateful if someone would be willing to explain why this might be true.

(**I apologize for the massive edits. The original question was this:**)

Let $A,B,G$ be finite etale group schemes over a connected scheme $S$. Let $T\rightarrow S$ be a finite etale morphism which trivializes $A,B,G$. Suppose $A\not\cong B$, but $A_T$ and $B_T$ are canonically isomorphic up to inner automorphisms. Must the quotient sheaves:

$$\mathcal{H}om^\text{surj}_S(A,G)/A\qquad\text{and}\qquad\mathcal{H}om^\text{surj}_S(B,G)/B$$
be canonically isomorphic? (here the action of $A$ and $B$ on the hom sheaf is by inner automorphisms on the source)

This original question seems to be clearly false - for example, take $A$ and $B$ to be nonisomorphic commutative group schemes with the same fiber.